# Какая погрешность alarmManager.setRepeating()

Tags: android, android-alarm-manager

От чего зависит или как узнать погрешность срабатывания alarmManager.setRepeating()?
Периодичность установлена на один раз в неделю, при этом мне нужно что бы он сработал в течение двух часов после расчётного времени срабатывания.

Порывшись в документации и в интернете, везде говорится что он может быть не точным с 19 API, но негде не говорится на сколько не точным и отчего это зависит.

Comment: Это зависит от состояния активности аппарата. Если в час `X` аппарат активен (экран светится, грубо говоря), то задача выполнится точно в срок. Если нет, то ближайшие задачи собираются вместе и выполняются кучкой, чтобы как можно реже будить аппарат и таким образом экономить заряд батареи. Если Вы хотите уложиться в определённый промежуток - используйте "окно" [`AlarmManager.setWindow(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setWindow(int,%2520long,%2520long,%2520android.app.PendingIntent)), но повторы придётся планировать дополнительно.

Comment: @woesss То есть это получается если никто не разбудит аппарат то он так может проспать сутки, двое и трое?